# Js button only works once?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Jeu.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"
    style="border-color: 'black'; border-width: 3px; border-style: solid">
      </canvas>
<br>
  <button type="button"onclick="dessiner()"><img src="Start.jpg"></button>

<script type="text/javascript">


  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

  var contexte = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var x

  var y

function ghost(){

ghost= new Image();
ghost.src = "ghost.jpg";
ghost.onload = function(){
contexte.drawImage(ghost,x,y,20,20)

}};

x = 32 +(Math.random() * (400-64));
y = 32 +(Math.random() * (400-64));

function dessiner(){

  ghost()
};




  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My objective with this code is to make the image "ghost.jpg" appear randomly in the canvas after every press of the button. The problem arises when i try to press the button multiple times. I was hoping that the picture would start appearing everywhere but it only works the first time and shows the image once.

Comment: you are initializing the value of x and y at wrong place. put them in dessiner() function and see the magic happen ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the functions `dessiner()` and `ghost.onload()` are being called multiple times, your variables `x` and `y` are being assigned random values only once, since they're defined on global scope.

So the image is being spawned every time you click, but... it's on the same position every time.

One way to approach the problem would be to assign X and Y values inside your `ghost.onload()`, or simply using `32 +(Math.random() * (400-64))` directly as parameters for your `drawImage()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Jeu.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"
    style="border-color: 'black'; border-width: 3px; border-style: solid">
      </canvas>
<br>
  <button type="button"onclick="dessiner()"><img style="width:24px; height:24px;" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/star-icon.png"></button>

<script type="text/javascript">

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var contexte = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x;
var y;

function ghost(){
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/halloween-1/128/42-512.png";
  image.onload = function(){
      contexte.drawImage(image,x,y,20,20)
  };
};

function dessiner(){
contexte.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //if you don't want to clear the canvar just comment this line ;) and you ll have ghostss all around
  x = 32 +(Math.random() * (400-64));
  y = 32 +(Math.random() * (400-64));
  ghost()
};




  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with the way the code is written.

The variable `ghost` not being preceeded by a `let` or a `var` has made `ghost` a global variable. This means that the first time you click `dessiner`, `ghost` the function is called but then in that function ghost is reassigned to an image and then all further attempts to call an image fail. This in your browser console will show an error on the second click onwards saying `Uncaught TypeError: ghost is not a function`, this can be fixed by simply adding a 'let' before your declaration of `ghost`

```
function ghost() {
  let ghost = new Image();
  ghost.src = "ghost.png";
  ghost.onload = function(){
      contexte.drawImage(image,x,y,20,20)
  };
}
```

After this there will be no more errors but you will still encounter the fact that the number of images don't increase when you click the button. In reality, the image is being generated but it's being placed exactly over where the last image was giving the illusion that nothing has changed. This is because your `x` and `y` values are the same everytime you generate a new image. This can be fixed by moving the creation of your `x` and `y` in the onload function like this and getting rid of other declarations of `x` and `y`

```
function ghost() {
  let ghost = new Image();
  ghost.src = "ghost.png";
  ghost.onload = function(){
    let x = 32 +(Math.random() * (400-64));
    let y = 32 +(Math.random() * (400-64));
    contexte.drawImage(image,x,y,20,20)
  };
}
```

At this point if you stop you will have the image appear in random spots after every click but the old image will still remain. If you do wanna get rid of the old image all you do is you clear the canvas before drawing the new image.

```
function dessiner() {
  contexte.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ghost();
}
```

ANd thats it you're done!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you.

Firstly: you had a variable ghost inside function ghost()
so when the function run first time, the ghost variable is set hence function ghost() is no longer valid as a function so change var ghost to var ghos
Secondly: you need to clear the canvas and get the variables x and y again before redrawing the canvas in funtion ghost()

```
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var contexte = canvas.getContext("2d");

        function ghost(){
            var x = 32 +(Math.random() * (400-64));
            var y = 32 +(Math.random() * (400-64));
            ghos= new Image();
            ghos.src = "icon.png";
            ghos.onload = function(){
            // Store the current transformation matrix of canvas
            contexte.save();

            // Use the identity matrix while clearing the canvas
            contexte.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
            contexte.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            // Restore the transform
            contexte.restore();
            contexte.drawImage(ghos,x,y,20,20)
            canvas.rem
        }};

        function dessiner(){
            ghost();
        }
```